# Get json from List<Map<String,string>>

Tags: java, json, cucumber-jvm

Can some one please help me where I am wrong in my code:

```
public void request_Body_From_Data(String json, DataTable requestBody)   throws Throwable {
    List<Map<String, String>> body = requestBody.asMaps(String.class, String.class);
    String converted_Json = convert_listmap_to_json_string(body);
    printJson(converted_Json);
}

public String convert_listmap_to_json_string(List<Map<String, String>> map) {
    JSONArray json_arr = new JSONArray();
    for (Map<String, String> list : map) {
        JSONObject json_obj = new JSONObject();
        for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : list.entrySet()) {
            String key = entry.getKey();
            String value = entry.getValue();
            try {
                if (key.equals("C")) {
                    break;
                } else {
                    json_obj.put(key, value);
                }
            } catch (JSONException jsone) {
                jsone.printStackTrace();
            }
            json_arr.put(json_obj);
        }
    }
    return json_arr.toString();
}
```

*Question:*

I would like to convert JSON, which are coming in list to Maps.

And I am reading List from Cucumber feature file.
Feature file looks like below:

```
   | A        | B    | C  |
  | trade     | test | ID |
  | Code      | 789  | ORDER|
```

I got below json format:
[{"B":"test","A":"trade"},{"B":"test","A":"trade"}

Expected result should be:

```
"A": {
  "trade": "test",
  "Code": "789",
  }
```

Comment: Thank you so much @Ark.I am in learning phase.

Answer (score 0):

Use Jackson [Library](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson). You can simply do this:-

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
mapper.enable(SerializationFeature.INDENT_OUTPUT); // If pretty-print is required
System.out.println(mapper.writeValueAsString(body));
```